# How do I run this python script on a list of urls instead of one url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that works with one url

How do I get it to loop through a list of urls and after every loop append the response to a dataframne. And then at the end of the list save the dataframe to a csv.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/AddressComplete/Interactive/Find/v2.10/json3ex.ws?Key=TF36-KU97-AB94-ZC85&Country=CAN&SearchTerm=L2A%200A2&LanguagePreference=en&LastId=CA%7CCP%7CENG%7C0A2-L2A&SearchFor=Everything&OrderBy=UserLocation&$block=true&$cache=true'

headers = {
    'authority': 'ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'origin': 'https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/ac/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

response_json = response.json()
results = response_json['Items']

results_subset_alpha = []
results_subset_beta = []

for result in results:
    results_subset_alpha.append(result['Text'])
    results_subset_beta.append(result['Description'])
    
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'results_subset_alpha': results_subset_alpha, 'results_subset_beta' : results_subset_beta})
new_df
```

Comment: Put `url` into a list (`urls`) and move the rest of the script inside a `for url in urls:` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this .

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/AddressComplete/Interactive/Find/v2.10/json3ex.ws?Key=TF36-KU97-AB94-ZC85&Country=CAN&SearchTerm=L2A%200A2&LanguagePreference=en&LastId=CA%7CCP%7CENG%7C0A2-L2A&SearchFor=Everything&OrderBy=UserLocation&$block=true&$cache=true',
    
]

# Headers
headers = {
    'authority': 'ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'origin': 'https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/ac/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response_json = response.json()
    results = response_json['Items']
    
    results_subset_alpha = [result['Text'] for result in results]
    results_subset_beta = [result['Description'] for result in results]
    
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({'results_subset_alpha': results_subset_alpha, 'results_subset_beta': results_subset_beta})
    
    final_df = final_df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)

final_df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

This script will loop through each URL in the urls list, make a request to each URL, extract the data from the response, and append it to a DataFrame. Finally, it will save the combined DataFrame to  CSV file named "results.csv"